# Stream File from server to Client Sharepoint

Tags: c#, file, stream, sharepoint-2013

I am trying in a sharepoint 2013 application to allow users to download multiple files at once, wich would take a lot of place in memory(in the case of downloading big files), so I was thinking about zipping this files first, then saving the zipped file on the server, sending it to the client, and after the download is done,I will delete it. T
his will not solve the problem, but I was thinking if there is a possibility to stream the ZIP file, sending few megabytes everytime, so that I don#t need to have the hall zipped file at once on the memory of the server.

Is that possible?

Comment: Mahmoud, I'm facing the same challenge here, so far I wasn't able to find an useful answer. I tried using WebClient.DownloadFile, but it downloads the file into the own server, and I need to download it to the client machine...

Comment: I have solved the problem,I will upload it later in github and share it with you

Comment: https://github.com/bafla133/ZipDownloader

Here it is, sorry for being too late